# A task scheduler with persistence

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a task scheduler package with data persistence in Go.

However, the logic seems super messy... even it seems passed all tests.

Is there any better way to structure the code and finish few unsolved TODO in the code? PR welcome after a review, thank you in advance.

```
package goscheduler

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/changkun/goscheduler/internal/pool"
    "github.com/changkun/goscheduler/internal/pq"
    "github.com/changkun/goscheduler/internal/store"
    "github.com/changkun/goscheduler/task"
)

var (
    worker        *Scheduler
    schedulerOnce sync.Once
)

// Scheduler is the actual scheduler for task scheduling
type Scheduler struct {
    mu    *sync.Mutex
    timer *time.Timer
    queue *pq.TimerTaskQueue
}

// Init internal connection pool to data store
func Init(url string) {
    pool.Init(url)
}

// New creates a temporary task scheduler
func New() *Scheduler {
    schedulerOnce.Do(func() {
        worker = &Scheduler{
            mu:    &sync.Mutex{},
            timer: nil,
            queue: pq.NewTimerTaskQueue(),
        }
    })
    return worker
}

// RecoverAll given tasks
func (s *Scheduler) RecoverAll(ts ...task.Interface) error {
    for _, t := range ts {
        if err := s.Recover(t); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Recover given task type
func (s *Scheduler) Recover(t task.Interface) error {
    ids, err := store.GetRecords()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, id := range ids {
        r := &store.Record{}
        if err := r.Read(id); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        data, _ := json.Marshal(r.Data)

        // Note: The following comparasion provides a generic mechanism in golang, which
        // unmarshals an unknown type of data into acorss multiple into an arbitrary variable.
        //
        // temp1 holds for a unset value of t, and temp2 tries to be set by json.Unmarshal.
        //
        // In the end, if temp1 and temp2 are appropriate type of tasks, then temp2 should
        // not DeepEqual to temp1, because temp2 is setted by store data.
        // Otherwise, the determined task is inappropriate type to be scheduled, jump to
        // next record and see if it can be scheduled.
        temp1 := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem().Type()).Interface().(task.Interface)
        temp2 := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(t).Elem().Type()).Interface().(task.Interface)
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &temp2); err != nil {
            continue
        }
        if reflect.DeepEqual(temp1, temp2) {
            continue
        }
        temp2.SetID(id)
        temp2.SetExecution(r.Execution)
        s.queue.Push(temp2)
    }
    s.resume()
    return nil
}

// SetupAll given tasks
func (s *Scheduler) SetupAll(ts ...task.Interface) error {
    for _, t := range ts {
        if err := s.Setup(t); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Setup a task into runner queue
func (s *Scheduler) Setup(t task.Interface) error {
    // save asap
    if err := store.Save(t); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.schedule(t)
    return nil
}

// LaunchAll given tasks
func (s *Scheduler) LaunchAll(ts ...task.Interface) error {
    for _, t := range ts {
        if err := s.Launch(t); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// Launch a task immediately
func (s *Scheduler) Launch(t task.Interface) error {
    t.SetExecution(time.Now().UTC())
    return s.Setup(t)
}

func (s *Scheduler) schedule(t task.Interface) {
    s.pause()
    defer s.resume()

    // if priority is able to be update
    if s.queue.Update(t) {
        return
    }

    s.queue.Push(t)
}

func (s *Scheduler) pause() {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()

    if s.timer != nil {
        s.timer.Stop()
    }
}

func (s *Scheduler) resume() {
    t := s.queue.Peek()
    if t == nil {
        return
    }
    s.mu.Lock()
    s.timer = time.NewTimer(t.GetExecution().Sub(time.Now().UTC()))
    timer := s.timer
    s.mu.Unlock()
    go func() {
        <-timer.C
        t := s.queue.Pop()
        if t == nil {
            return
        }
        s.resume()
        s.arrival(t)
    }()
}

func (s *Scheduler) arrival(t task.Interface) {
    ok, err := store.Lock(t)
    if err != nil || !ok {
        return
    }
    defer func(t task.Interface) {
        if err := store.Unlock(t); err != nil {
            // no need to hadle unlock fail
            // since there is a timeout on redis
            return
        }
    }(t)

    s.execute(t)
}

func (s *Scheduler) verify(t task.Interface) (*time.Time, error) {
    r := &store.Record{}
    if err := r.Read(t.GetID()); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    taskTime := t.GetExecution()
    if taskTime.Before(r.Execution) {
        return &r.Execution, nil
    }
    return &taskTime, nil
}
func (s *Scheduler) execute(t task.Interface) {
    execution, err := s.verify(t)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if execution.Before(time.Now().UTC()) {
        retry, err := t.Execute()
        if retry || err != nil {
            s.retry(t)
            return
        }
        if err := store.Delete(t); err != nil {
            // TODO: Generally, this is not able to be fail.
            // However it may caused by the lost of connection.
            // Though task will be recovered then app restarts,
            // but it may leads an inconsistency, we need other
            // means to solve this problem
            return
        }
        return
    }
    s.mu.Lock()
    s.queue.Push(t)
    s.mu.Unlock()
}

func (s *Scheduler) retry(t task.Interface) {
    t.SetExecution(t.GetExecution().Add(t.GetRetryDuration()))
    if err := s.Setup(t); err != nil {
        // TODO: If Setup() is fail because of redis failure,
        // directly schedule the task without any hesitate
        // In case it may leads a problem of unabiding task
        // scheduling
        s.schedule(t)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/changkun/sched

Comment: @Graipher Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I attached the major part of my code. You can also find attached material in the link.